# What いく supposed to mean here?

Tags: translation

I came across this sentence:[image]

I know that いくcould mean 'to go' or 'to move' but I don't think it means something like that here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「いく」 here is a subsidiary verb, which is why it is written in kana.  It is attached to the "main" verb 「蝕{むしば}む」 to form 「蝕んでいく」.

What 「いく」 does as a subsidiary verb is to express the **increasing and/or continuing tendency** of the action described by the main verb.

"to keep on (main verb)ing"

"to (main verb) more and more"

> "(It turns into a) shapeless malice and continuously eats/ruins a human body from the inside."