# I'm wrestling with the first って in 借金が雪だるま式に増えてってるって噂だよ

Tags: translation, subsidiary-verbs, particle-って

The sentence in question:

> 借金が雪だるま式に増えてってるって噂だよ

My best guess is that the first って is a contracted from of いる. Whatever it is that we're addressing seems to be suffering from a financial crisis. Then why not put it like 「増えているって噂だよ」, rather than what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 増えてってる is a contraction of 増えて**い**ってる (or 増えて**い**って**い**る).

Here いって(い)る is the progressive of the [subsidiary verb いく](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43482/1628). (This verb derives from 行く, but being a subsidiary verb is usually written in *kana*.)

Attaching to a main verb (here 増える) it characterizes the action described by this verb as ongoing or as getting stronger.

> 借金が雪だるま式に増えてってるって噂だよ
>
> people say that debt keeps on multiplying like a snowball effect, but that's not true

---

For more general information about subsidiary verbs see [What is a subsidiary verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/1628)

Comment: Thanks for a quick and clear reply! That subsidiary いく totally slipped my mind, and now I got it under my belt.